# Talend TRestClient: geocoding and combination of both flows (rows) afterwards

Tags: google-maps-api-3, talend

I am currently working on a small Talend job, which imports CSV data, gets the address field and sends the address to Google Maps API for geocoding. Afterwards, I need to combine both the input and geocoding data.

My problem is, that the combination of initial data row and geocoding result seems not possible; After passing the TRestClient, all reference to the input data seems gone.

Here's my non-final data flow:

```
Subjob 1: CSVInput --> THashMapOutput
    |
    |
Subjob 2: THashInput --> tRestClient --> tExtractJSONFields --> tMap --> tBufferOutput
                                                                  | (Lookup)
                                                                  |
                                                                tHashInput
   |
   |
Subjob 3: tBufferInput --> tFileOutputDelimited
```

Herein, the last tMap does not have a foreign key aka reference to the input row. Therefore the join creates the cross product of all different combinations of input and geocoded raw.

**Is there a way to combine both input and geocoding results? Can we configure tRestClient to forward inputs as well?**

(a combination of two resulting csv files seems to fail for the same missing identifier)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answer was quite easy:

1. Assume you have the first link in subjob 2 called row2.
2. Then you can open the second tMap component.
3. Remove the lookup shown above.
4. Add the references to row 2 within tMap: e.g. row2.URL, row2.Name

Et voila: Now you get each row combined of geocoded result and original data.